# Formatting a date in python

Tags: python, date, format

I have a variable called `created = created[1],created[2], created[0]` that outputs a date in the form of [(12, 11, 2019)]. I want the date to be formatted like 12/11/2019. How would I got about changing the formatting in python.

```
created = time.localtime(user.created / 1000)
created = created[1],created[2], created[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line can be converted into string by

`created = str(created[1]) + '/' + str(created[2]) + '/'  + str(created[0])`

Then you get what you want to get.

The only thing to remember - if you `print(type(created))` now, you will see that created is string type!